# Unable to delete MS Graph Subscription

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When using MS Graph Explorer, calling

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/
```

returns i.e. two entries, with resource of user's onedrive root.
When I'm deleting one of those with

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/{id}
```

I'm getting Status 204, but querying for all subscriptions, that deleted item is returned as well.
Trying to DELETE or GET that item again results in

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "The object was not found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "b62bc766-c551-4460-a04d-2fa0a390283e",
            "date": "2019-09-04T15:40:17"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the GET operation is returning a cached (in the service) data set.

Unless you are still notification calls in your service, I would assume the DELETE worked, and the GET call will eventually not return removed subscriptions.